# Generate Last logon report exchange server powshell

Tags: exchange, powershell, exchange-2010

With this command in shell `get-MailboxStatistics -Server servername  | Select-Object DisplayName | Sort LastLogonTime -Descending  | Export-csv c:\export.csv`

I am able to generate a full reports of last logon with display name.

but I also need a column showing the last user that accessed the mailbox as we have some mailboxes that are shared with many users is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add ",LastLoggedonUserAccount" after DisplayName.

```
get-MailboxStatistics -Server servername  | Select-Object DisplayName,LastLoggedOnUserAccount | Sort LastLogonTime -Descending  | Export-csv c:\export.csv
```

Comment: Thanks but What i did is exported all the mailbox who are shared and got the last logon manually